# save fields in data base throught Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have 2 files :
- form.php :

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function()
        {

            $('#r').click(function()
            {
            pseudo= $("#pseudo").val();
            password= $("#password").val();

            $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"insert.php",
                    data:'pseudo='+pseudo+'&password='password,
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        if(data == 1)
                        {
                            alert("ddd");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("lll");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>


        <center>
            <form class="well form-inline" method="post" action="buscarUsuario.php">
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="" id="r">Save</a>
                <input type="text" style="height: 30px" class="span4" placeholder="Pseudo" id="pseudo" />
                <span id="error"></span>
                <span id="ok"></span>
                <input type="password" style="height: 30px" class="span4" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
                <button type="submit" style="width: 95px" class="btn btn-primary" value="Entrar" name="Entrar">Entrar</ button>     
            </form>
        <center>

</body>
</html>
```

and i want to save pseudo and password in my data base through this file insert.php :

```
<?php

require "connecttoBD.php";

$pseudo= $_POST["pseudo"];
$password= $_POST["password"];



$sql="INSERT INTO usuarios (pseudo,password) VALUES ('$pseudo,$password') ";
$req=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

echo "1";

?>
```

but when i fill out the 2 fields and press the button Save I have not saved the 2 fields in my data base.
can anyone help me please ?
thank you.

Comment: have you tried turning on error reporting in php.ini

Comment: Probably because you did not name your form fields. Try adding `name="pseudo"` and `name="password"` accordingly.

Comment: you aren't sending the password value back, only pseudo

Comment: @Fred-ii- he is doing ajax so he only needs ids

Comment: What they said above, and: use prepared statement! Does not matter if this is a 'test' application or you are 'just learning' (in the later case this is THE time to learn about it). 

Never, not, always, yes prepared statements.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Markasoftware Ajax gets me again. lol ok.. I'll let you guys help out. ;-) (Ajax Cleaned me out) *as it were*

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: My new secure password is "') DROP TABLE usuarios" see it has lower case upper case and symbols

Answer (score 2):

```
data:'pseudo='+pseudo,
```

**change in**

```
data:{ pseudo:pseudo,
       password:password
},
```

in your ajax request

Comment: also, i find `.preventDefault()` on the click event to help too.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$sql="INSERT INTO usuarios (pseudo,password) VALUES ('$pseudo','$password') ";
$req=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

and insted of

```
if(data == 1)
```

use

```
if($.trim(data) == 1)
```